# Excel Arrays: average and if combining more than one criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a data for an assessment tool that has about 20 categories and about 200 items scored 0-3. The first half of the tool is mandatory, other sections are optional so there are a lot of blank areas. 4 items have the option of N/A.

I currently use arrays to gather *average if* data over multiple columns for each category. I got help on another forum and am including the formulas below as well. I use two different ones, as mentioned in some of the data ranges all items cells require a score, and for some sections, it is optional or not scored at all. 
In the sample grid below, I need to find the average for all the data columns combined (**Q1-Q4**) based one Assessment types **B** and **N**. Note: some scores are given option for n/a

```
T   Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
N   0   0   3   2
B   1   2   3   
N   1   1   0   0
N       
D   0   n/a 2   3
O1  0   1   1   0
O1  2   0   0   0
O2  2   n/a 0   0
```

The grid I pasted here doesn't seem to show correctly and I can't paste an image of it. Below it doesn't resemble my grid at all. So let's say that in column **A** I have different codes for assessment type. **B**, **D**, **N**, **O1**, **O2**. 
In columns **B-E** I have scores for each question. Some cells are blank for one whole row, a couple of rows in column C are marked N/A. So row two might be: 
**N  0  1  3  0**; row two might be **B 0 N/a 2  2**. Row three might be **B** (empty cells)

Current formulas for using one criteria:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ANSAt!H:H="B",ANSAt!J:AC))
```

and to not include blanks in sections that have lots of blanks

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ANSAt!$H:$H="B", IF(XMod!G:Y<>"", XMod!G:Y)))
```

If anyone can help me show the example I would appreciate it :) I even tried to use the Snip tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort on the "T" column then you can use this:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,INDEX($B$2:$E$9,MATCH(H2,$A$2:$A$9,0),1):INDEX($B$2:$E$9,MATCH(H2,$A$2:$A$9,0)+COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,H2)-1,4))
```

[image]

EDIT:

While you are trying to understand the above I thought I would add one more for you.  This formula does not care if it is sorted or not:

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(INDEX(($A$2:$A$9=H2)*$B$2:$E$9,)),"",INDEX(($A$2:$A$9=H2)*$B$2:$E$9,)))/SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX(($A$2:$A$9=H2)*ISNUMBER($B$2:$E$9),)))
```

This is an array formula.  It needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode.  If done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Also it you want to hard code either of these formula with the lookup value directly replace the H2 reference with the desired String; `"N"`.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty complicated! I haven't yet figured out where it says to average the data section if row A has B or N. Although you said to sort, so maybe that's where I'm missing something. I've asked a colleague to look at this too since she gets it more than me :)

Comment: @Avanell I put it in a small table in H and I.  The formula is pasted in I and refers to H,  If you want to hard code the lookup then change all the references of `H2` to `"N"` or `"B"` or whatever.  there are three references that need to be changed.

Comment: We kind of get it...haven't tried out yet but will :)

Comment: @Avanell what are your concerns, about trying it?  Also see the second formula I just put up.  It works without sorting.